# SELECT inside CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables with data like that

Elements

```
ID  Type  Value
------------------
1   Text  AAA
2   Image BBB
3   Video CCC
```

Texts

```
ItemID  Language   Text
------------------------
AAA     English    Hi There!
AAA     French     Hi There in french!
DDD     English    Some other text
```

I want to create a select statement that when the `Type` from `Elements` table is 'Text' the select statement will pull the text value from `Texts` table, the text must be restrict to one languge
so the result will be

```
ID  Type  Value   Text
-----------------------
1   Text  AAA     Hi There in French! ---This text is only the 'French' text
2   Image BBB     NULL
3   Video CCC     NULL
```

**EDIT**

I figure i can do this staement:

```
SELECT *,
 CASE EE.[Type]
  WHEN 'Text' THEN (
     SELECT [Text] FROM Texts 
     WHERE ItemID=EE.Value
     AND LanguageID='English'
  ) END as Text
  FROM Elements EE
 WHERE EE.ID = 1
```

can you think on a better solution?

Comment: Is the language dependent on the CASE?

Comment: I've edited the question with exmaple

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** to return one of several possible values. It is **NOT** a control flow statement, like in other languages. You **CANNOT** use it to control whether one or another `SELECT` statement is executed - use  `IF .. ELSE` for that

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be a case?  Why not Join, what's the end game?

```
SELECT type, value, language, text
FROM elements
LEFT JOIN texts ON value = itemID and elements.type = 'Text' and  LanguageID='English'
```

Comment: Because of the two languages for each ID - I'll get 2 result for one ID

Comment: Ultimately, what do you want the query to do though?  You can still use a join and also restrict it to  `LanguageID='English'`

Comment: How do you know what language to select, is this input from the user somehow?

Comment: yeah depend on the user selection

Answer (score 0):

This may also help you.

```
SELECT      E.*,T.Texts
FROM        [Elements] E
LEFT JOIN   [Texts] T 
ON          E.Value = T.ItemID
WHERE       T.Language = 'French'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the selected language is based on user selection I would go for something like previous guys but just with the parameter:

```
SELECT      E.*,T.Texts
FROM        [Elements] E
LEFT JOIN   [Texts] T 
ON          E.Value = T.ItemID and T.Language = @Language
```

Joins are faster than subqueries and also more read-able. You should avoid using subqueries as much as possible. If you would like this in your way [using `CASE`] I would go for something like this:

```
SELECT *,
 CASE EE.[Type]
  WHEN 'Text' THEN  TT.Text
  END as Text
  FROM Elements EE
  LEFT JOIN Texts TT on EE.Value = TT.ItemId and TT.Language = @Language
```